# What are the default grid widths for Foundation 6 full width and non full-width?

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

Even though I am know Foundation is responsive, I am trying to craft precise photoshop documents with certain breakpoints and trying to understand how foundation establish the grid elements sizes (by default).

Let's say for example a media query of // XXLarge screens
@media only screen and (min-width: 120.063em) { } /* min-width 1921px, xxlarge screens */ 12 columns

[image: this is my current grid which I used based on the foundation PSD that I purchased but I think it's wrong]

Question1: are the gutters applied by default? or the by default the system applies no gutters, just pure columns?

Question2: does foundation applies outer gutter (or outer margins) automatically?

Question3: what is the total width for a non full-width row considering screensize of 1920?

Question4: what are the sizes of the columns, gutters in this case of screen width of 1921?

Question5: how should I prepare my document if I want to follow defaults with the new XY grid?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the documentation info that was uncovered, I found out more information on the new XY Grid by contacting Zurb:

The XY Grid is the Default grid in 6.4+

No gutters by default. Cells can get spacing in the form of margin or padding
If you add spacing between cells, it will apply on both sides of each cell.

The default width of the grid-container is 1200px. This can be changed easily. You can create a grid that is fluid width as well.

Cells are a % of the grid container or the screen width. So if you have 4 cells in a grid using the medium-3 class, each will be 25% of the width. You can also have cells be auto or shrink size. Shrink will take up the width of the content inside, and grow will expand to fill remaining space.

Answer (score -1):

Find answers to all your questions by reading the [Foundation for Sites 6 Docs >>](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/xy-grid.html)

Comment: I found some information such as the box container (all columns+grid) being as 1200px as default considering a size size width of 1920, which means when the full width is NOT used, there is an extra outer space of 720 pixels in total or 360px in each. My question is about the outer gutter or how the gutter is created, I saw some examples on codepen and sometimes it seems the gutter is one entity which spans as a default of 20px, but I've seen examples that they are in fact two instances of 10px coming from each side of the opposing columns (like padding). But what about in the XY grid?

Comment: The link above points to the Foundation XY Grid page.
Sounds like you need to read the sections with Headings ...
> Gutters.
> Grid Container Full.

Comment: yes I read these sections but it doesn't talk about outer gutter (the last two gutters on the last two columns). Note: I am not talking about the inner gutters. I checked a code on codepen and it seems that these gutters on the regular grid (not XY) they are not even, the outer gutters are half the size of the gutters. In this case the gutters are 30px and the outer gutters are 15px . http://i.imgur.com/qpfo0Si.png - check this image. I don't understand why you keep pointing me to the documentation instead of trying to help out understanding the information, it feels like arrogance to me